# Filter Large Data Sets on Dates with Command Line

Tags: grep, columns

I have a huge data sets that consists of tab separated values that are stored in rows. An example row looks like this:

```
Dec 4 14:37:36.381651 algorc1 [27751:l@27932]/error:   [] - [T0000A124M5] Didn't receive message!
```

I want to filter out all messeages before a specific time on a specific date.

My thoughts are this:

```
grep <file> | select everything in first column larger than date | select everything in second column larger than time
```

I just don't know how I can select by column and I don't know about larger and smaller dates and times.

So I don't know that much ;-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sed` to filter these.  This simple example assumes you know the exact start/end time:

```
sed -n '/Dec 4 14:37:36.381651/,/Dec 5 14:32:36.391572/' filename
```

You cannot round those time/dates to values that don't exist. For example:

```
sed -n '/Dec 4 14:30:00.000000/,/Dec 5 14:29:59.999999/' filename
```

wouldn't work unless the specified times were both in the log.

---

If you want to filter between two arbitrary time/dates that aren't in the log, then `awk` may help:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=":| +"} {current = mktime("2014 "c($1)" "$2" "$3" "$4" "$5); if (current >= mktime ("2014 12 04 14 30 0") && current <= mktime("2014 12 05 14 29 59")) {print $0 }} function c(s){return(sprintf("%02d\n",(match("JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec",$1)+2)/3)) }' filename
```

The selected time/dates are in YYYY MM DD HH MM SS format.  You'll also note that the year is hard-coded in as your logs don't contain the year - I've assumed it's this year.

The above one-liner, but better formatted and with comments:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
    # Split line into fields using colon or spaces
    FS=":| +"
}
{
    # Generate the timestamp of the current line from the first 5 fields.
    # Use the function c(), defined below, to convert 3 letter months to numerical
    current = mktime("2014 "c($1)" "$2" "$3" "$4" "$5);
    # If the timestamp of the current line is between two specified
    # timestamps then print the whole line
    if (current >= mktime ("2014 12 08 15 0 0") && current <= mktime("2014 12 08 16 05 00")) 
        {print $0 }
}
function c(s) {
    # Function to convert three letter month to numerical
    # If s == Jan then returns 1. If s == Aug, returns 8
    return(sprintf("%02d\n",(match("JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec",$1)+2)/3))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One solution, converting date to epoch :

```
while read month dm hour rest; do
    d=$(date -d"$month $dm $hour" "+%m%d%H%M%S")
    echo "$d $rest"
done < file | awk '$1 < 1204143737' # print all lines before this date
```